# What would be better way to build a database model + jpa layer in an an agile/iterative way?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

To be precise on the context, I'm working on a single dev instance of a relatively small but increasing database (~20 tables).

I've tried to iterate this way :

1. Apply new requirements in a DB designer tool
2. Generate a SQL script
3. Drop existing database and execute the full script
4. Execute the script filling the initial data (written by hand).
5. Generate JPA entities with Dali + EclipseLink tools (clicking in the tools to restrict navigation between entities and selecting id generation method).
6. Comparing each of the generated entity to the previous version to get back my customisation (java.util.Date => java.time.LocalDateTime for example, but also toString, equals, hashcode methods when needed).

This way of iterating would work really well if I could customize the JPA entity generation itself and save this generation customization for further generation.

Comment: Did you have a look already at Liquibase and other DB migration tools (e.g. Flyway)?

Comment: I did, but it would only improve database versionning and migrations from one env to an other. Here I'm talking about a single dev instance of a relatively small database (~20 tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I was wrong to try to customize the JPA entity generator (entities generation from tables).

To work iteratively on a data model and data layer where you don't know all of the requirements from start, the trick is to use the generator with no customization at all, and put the generated classes under source control.

You customize only a copy of these generated classes to fit your needs (types, navigation, additional methods/enums, ...). This copy becomes your peristent layer.

When the data model evolves (new tables, new attributes, renamings, type change), you use the generator and replace the existing generated classes with the newly generated classes. This way, your source control system (probably git) can tell you exactly which classes are new, which ones have been deleted and which class of your persistent layer need which modifications.

This is the most reliable and efficient practice I've found so far to work on a datamodel iteratively, keeping the benefit of using a generator after first generation.